# How to convert a big 1D array into series of small key:pair objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make free hand drawing sketchpad in threeJS. Most of the part has been done and able to draw the shapes. Now my next step is to use the [simplify-JS](https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js) for simplifying the points in my polygon. 
The concern is that I am passing my array as buffer geometry and using Line Mesh to draw on screen. I am creating array like [x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z... and so on] till MAX_POINTS which is 10000 in my case. Example

```
Vertices[0.555,0.323,298,0.585,0.353,298,0.615,0.373,298...continuous].
```

now how can I convert this vertices to

```
Vertices[{x:0.555,y:0.323,z:298}, {x:0.585,y:0.353,z:298},{x:0.615,y:0.373,z:298}]
```

..and so on till Vertices.length.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in outer for loop traverse all. and in inner for loop declare a temp and run that 3 times by counter. temp will be object of 3 values. dump that to a new array every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to traverse the array and push objects in a new array.

```
var vertices = [0.555,0.323,298,0.585,0.353,298,0.615,0.373,298];
var convertedVertices = [];

for(let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 3){
  convertedVertices.push({ x: vertices[i], y: vertices[i+1], z: vertices[i+2] })
}

console.log(convertedVertices);
```

UPDATED:

To convert the array back the to the 1D Vertices.

```
let revert = convertedVertices.reduce(((acc, obj) => acc.concat(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z)), []);
```

<s>JSBin: https://jsbin.com/sohakufope/edit?js,console</s>

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/bodazugeco/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks @Faheem for the quick reply. working as charm. i forgot that we can actually push x: , y: and z: also along with the values.. dumb me!!

Comment: **@SIM**, What if the number of elements in your array is not a multiple of 3.e.g. `[2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 9.2]` so in this case you will get `[{x:2.3, y:4.5, z=6.7}, {x:9.2, y:undefined, z:undefined}]`. If it is ok then no problem otherwise you need some simple checks in your code to put default values like `0.0` etc. It is based on the JS library if throws errors for `undefined` values or not.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani : Thanks, but here my array will always be multiple of 3 because I am drawing in 3d and single point on the viewport will have 3 values representing x,y, and z. I hope I am making sense

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani : now my concern is that I will get a simplified array of objects, let say 16 objects of x,y,z each with each having key:value pair. how to convert it back to a single dimension array again, same like the one is passed as input earlier

Comment: @SIM, Check the answer. I've added a new line to change the array back to 1D.

Comment: `arr = [];` `for(i=0; i<convertedVertices.length; i+=1) { arr.concat([convertedVertices.x, convertedVertices.y, convertedVertices.z]); }` will also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nverts = [];
for(var i=0;i<vertices.length;i+=3)nverts.push(new THREE.Vector3(vertices[i],vertices[i+1],vertices[i+2]);
```

Comment: Thanks @manthrax, this one is also working. Thanks for sticking to three JS context. Accepted answer is also the same and will see which one to use after pushing data to simplify-js. Thanks Again

Comment: Cheers  :) Happy THREE.js'ing!

Comment: Quick note about the accepted answer.. pushing bare objects instead of new Vector3 objects may result in undefined behavior if the receiving classes are expecting real Vector3's!  But it might be fine.. :)

Answer (score 1):

hope it helps

```
var vertices = [
    0.555,0.323,298,
    0.585,0.353,297,
    0.615,0.373,296,
    0.123,0.456,295,
    0.789,0.012,294,
    0.234,0.569,293];

if (vertices.length % 3 === 0) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i < vertices.length; i+=3) {
        result.push({ x: vertices[i], y: vertices[i+1], z: vertices[i+2] });
    }
    console.table(result);
}
```

Comment: internal logic is same as accepted answer, except the elimination of for loop, so it will also work. thanks though @Neo Choi

Answer (score 0):

Would have been nice if you had test  data  for this  but I think something similar  to following should work fine.

```
const keysMap = ['x', 'y', 'z']
let transformedArr = [];
let vertices = [0.555,0.323,298,0.585,0.353,298,0.615,0.373,298...continuous]
while (vertices.length) {
  vector = {};
  vertices.slice(o, 2).forEach( (val, ind) => {vector[keyMap[ind]] = val} );
  transformedArr.push(vector);
  vertices = vertices.slice(3);
}
```

Comment: I believe OP is trying to convert to a 3d vector object, i.e. {x,y,z}.